# TYPO3 backend deeplink to page record

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, deeplink

I am using version 8.7 of TYPO3 and intended to use a link that leads directly to the backend to edit a record (page). I tried anything like `typo3/backend.php?edit=57` but got a error:

> file not found

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to get a deeplink to a page record in the backend. What exactly do you want to achive? Maybe there are other possibilities.

Comment: You may try bookmarks (backend shortcuts).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll use the suggestion below from Rudy Gnode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`typo3/backend.php?edit=57` was the way to do it up until TYPO3 6.2, but the backend URL changed to `typo3/index.php` in TYPO3 7.6. It still works kind of, however you need a security token which is generated by the core. The URL now is `typo3/index.php?route=%2Fmain&edit=57&token=...`. There isn't really an easy way to generate URL with a valid token like that from outside TYPO3 though.

If you want to create a link inside a custom module to edit a record you can use `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Utility\BackendUtility::editOnClick()` or if you're using a Fluid template, the `\TYPO3\CMS\Backend\ViewHelpers\Link\EditRecordViewHelper` ViewHelper. More on that you can find here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/8.7/ApiOverview/Examples/EditLinks/

Comment: It works. I'll try to figure out how to use the token in a link called an external platform. In my case, siteimprove. Thank you.

Comment: @Sednaref You should not try to send this token to the external platform. Exposing the CSRF token makes the token itself useless and your site vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the extension `pxa_siteimprove` deep links are of the following form:

```
https://example.com/typo3/index.php?tx_siteimprove_goto=page:{page_uid}:{language_uid}
```

The parameter `language_uid` is optional. An example link to a page with uid 42 looks like this:

```
https://example.com/typo3/index.php?tx_siteimprove_goto=page:42
```

Optionally we can include a language uid (e.g. 1). Without a language uid set it defaults to `0`:

```
https://example.com/typo3/index.php?tx_siteimprove_goto=page:42:1
```

If you want to create deep links for other purposes, you can look how this extension creates the deep link in `Pixelant\PxaSiteimprove\Hooks\DeepLinkingHandler`. In a first hook it just saves the page uid to the backend user session and in a later hook reuses this information to redirect to the desired page by setting the following global variable:

```
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->uc['startModuleOnFirstLogin'] = 'web_layout->id=' . (int)$pageId . '&SET[language]=' . (int)$languageId;
```